# what is the difference between stop and pause？

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

When a process instance is running ,

I click the stop button,

then the current running task will be kill or will it wait for the end of the task being executed?

version:1.3.4

Answer (score 1):

yes, you are right.
a stop will kill the running tasks, while pause does not stop the running task, it will wait for the finish of the running tasks